# unable to set CCLabelTTF anchorPoint

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i am using CCLabelTTF together with NSLocalizedString, but i am not able to set the anchor point. (I want all my buttons to be aligned left, so it should be ccp(0, 0.5f), but the result is always center, in any localization. 
the following methods are in a Helper.m, and i call CCLabelTTF* startLabel = [Helper createItemLabelWithStringUpperCase: @"PLAY!!!"]

```
+(CCLabelTTF*) createLocalizedLabelWithStringUpperCase: (NSString*) str color: (ccColor3B) c fontSize: (int) s {
    NSString* font;
    if ([Helper useCutomFontFile]) {
        font = @"font.ttf";
    }
    else {
        font = @"Arial";
    }
    CCLabelTTF* label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:NSLocalizedString(str, nil) fontName:font fontSize:s];
    CCLOG(@"%@\n", str);
    CCLOG(@"%@\n", NSLocalizedString(str, nil));

    label.color = c;
    return label;
}

+(CCLabelTTF*) createLocalizedLabelWithStringUpperCase: (NSString*) str color: (ccColor3B) c {
    return [Helper createLocalizedLabelWithStringUpperCase:str color:c fontSize:32];
}

+(CCLabelTTF*) createUnlocalizedLabelWithString:(NSString *)str color:(ccColor3B)c fontSize: (int) s {
    CCLabelTTF* label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString: str fontName:@"font.ttf" fontSize:s];
    label.color = c;
    return label;
}
+(CCLabelTTF*) createUnlocalizedLabelWithString: (NSString*) str color: (ccColor3B) c {
    return [Helper createUnlocalizedLabelWithString:str color:c fontSize:32];
}
+(CCLabelTTF*) createItemLabelWithStringUpperCase: (NSString*) str {
    CCLabelTTF* label = [Helper createLocalizedLabelWithStringUpperCase:str color:ccBLACK];
    label.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0.5f);
    return label;
}
```

btw, where can i find some common localized vocabulary like "play", 'resume' 'pause" etc? i don't think google translate is accurate enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at CCLabelTTF Class Reference here:

```
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_label_t_t_f.html
```

And try this method:

```
labelWithString:dimensions:alignment:fontName:fontSize:
```

or this:

```
initWithString:dimensions:alignment:fontName:fontSize:
```

To create a CCStringTTF with alignment.

Alignment could be one of the followings:

```
CCTextAlignmentLeft     
CCTextAlignmentCenter   
CCTextAlignmentRight
```

Comment: no they are actually different labels and i want to align 5 labels to the left, so i need to set the anchor point to ccp(0, 0.5f).                   btw, do you know where can i find some common localized vocabulary like "play", 'resume' 'pause" etc? i don't think google translate is accurate enough

Comment: You mean you have 5 different labels that you use like buttons?

Comment: Regarding your other question... I don't know any common localized vocalubary, but maybe this would be useful:
http://www.wordreference.com/
Please consider to ask a new question regarding this issue: it could be useful for other programmers too.

Comment: yes, all the buttons are [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel: xx block: xx. ] and then i put the items into a single CCMenu menuWithItems: , , , nil]. i don't think a dictionary is accurate since it may not be as 'local' and may have different meanings.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand correctly your goal, but... if you want to align your buttons inside a CCMenu try to use padding: alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:padding

Comment: That explains it: anchorPoint is ignored or reset if you turn the label into a menu item. Instead, you may have better luck changing the anchorPoint of the CCMenuItem object itself. However this may or may not be handled correctly by CCMenu. There are some position or anchorPoint changes that will cause the graphics to be displayed where you want it, but the touch detection is still where CCMenu thinks the menu item should be.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D setting anchorPoint of CCMenuItem works! thank you!